# Active record query select_all, prepared statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Am trying to write a prepared statement like below :

```
@fofs = FileOrFolder.connection.select_all("select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like","%#{params[:search]}%")
```

It turns out to be a wrong query on mysql console. Does not take the variable %#{params[:search]}% value in to query

Please correct my query ...

console messages:

```
Parameters: {"search"=>"do", "cluster_id"=>"2", "datasetid"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
  %do% (0.2ms)  select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like):
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Try a placeholder ?`**

"select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like ?","%#{params[:search]}%"

See the question mark in the above statement which will be filled in by the params that follows the comma.

IF the above the statement doesnt work, this must work, using "+" to concatenate, beware of the space next to "like"

```
sql = "select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like <<space>>" + "%#{params[:search]}%"

FileOrFolder.connection.select_all(sql)
```

Comment: its not working ..... its taking it as a complete string and for the like parameter it s not in the quotes .... 

output sql : select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like %d% ....................

%d% is not in quotes ...

Comment: "select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like << >>" + "%#{params[:search]}%" ...also not working !

Comment: "select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like " + "%#{params[:search]}%" ..here..dont give <<space>>, i meant leave a literal space...

Comment: ...tried that too ..... dint work ..... it stops after 'like' this way when i check in the console  select * from newtestdocB.file_or_folders where name like

Comment: then it means params[:search] is nil, just like here...1.9.3-p385 :003 > "sadf " + "#{nil}"
 => "sadf "